# iTextSharp signature from CAC in mvc view

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, itext

I have looked in many places and downloaded many examples and lots of code.  Can someone tell me if it is even possible to read certificates from a web client in an MVC view and drop it into a PDF?

Comment: Are you talking about client certificates or do you want to just be able to inspect [remote TLS certificates](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15343898/231316) (like https://www.microsoft.com) in .Net (MVC doesn't really matter in this case).

Comment: I want to inspect the certs on the CAC smart card inserted in the card reader on the client.

Comment: Short of installing code on the user's end, the best that you can do is prompt the user to select the certificate that they want to use (if they even have one). See [this for configuring IIS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753983(v=ws.10).aspx) to do it. You'll only ever get the public key, however, so you'll have nothing to sign with.

Comment: Maybe, depending on your environment - I was able to [create a working prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949243/sign-pdf-with-smartcard-in-web-context-using-capicom-itextsharp) with the **much appreciated** help of @mkl.