# Digital signature pdf from web using smart card

Tags: javascript, wcf, certificate, digital-signature, smartcard

I am developing web application. The backend is a C# WCF service, and the frontend is html, JS. I need to **digitally sign a PDF using a smart card on the client side**. Does anyone know how I can solve this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You may be able to refer to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949243/how-do-i-sign-a-pdf-with-a-smart-card-in-a-web-context-using-itext) to get what you want.

Comment: To insert digital signature to PDF files, consider using a PDF toolkit like LEADTOOLS. See the tutorial [here](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/tutorials/dotnet-console-add-a-digital-signature-to-a-pdf.html) for a C# example on how to do this. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)

Comment: Refer to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55676351/9659885 - this also points to working POC of PDF signing...